# Sharing same code base for Web (Angular 4) and Mobile (Ionic 3)

Tags: angular, cordova, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am curious to know if I can use the same code base for my web application which is already built in Angular 4 and mobile application (needs to be developed in Ionic 3).

Firstly, I've no prior knowledge of Ionic 3. So, I was checking the Ionic 3 documentation and got to know that I'll have to update the normal HTML tags with Ionic tags (ion-).

So, what I want to confirm is after updating the HTML tags, can I use the updated code for the web as well? Will it work the way it's working now? If yes, then is it a good practice to do so?

What will be the Pros and Cons of sharing the same code base?

Comment: You can use Cordova (not Ionic) and not change code or html

Comment: Ionic 3 uses cordova I guess

Comment: I want to say that you can use Cordova without Ionic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You **cannot do** that. But you can develop web applications (`PWA`-progressive web apps) using `Ionic`. That is the only way where you can use the same code base.other way around it won't work. But you can use most of the `Angular` components within `Ionic 3` projects.

But if you need to develop `native Ionic` app then you have to use `native`(`iOS` & `Android`) Cordova plugins. Most of those plugins are not working with web apps.

So if you need to use the same code base then you need to develop `PWA` app with `ionic`. That is the only way I can think of.